# HaProxy Load Balancer and Nginx Basic Auth

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have a nginx server with basic auth

```
 location / {
      root   /var/www/mywebsite.com;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth
  }
```

The server is behind an HAProxy Load Balancer. is there a way that I can have the load balancer send the username and password to nginx to authenticate?

Comment: How should the configuration be if the authentication is for Nginx not HA? Or is it impossible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, two step answer.

Step 1 Base64 encode the username and password. Lets say the user is johndoe and the password is abc123.

```
$bash: echo -n johndoe:abc123 | openssl enc -a
Output: am9obmRvZTphYmMxMjM=
```

Step 2 is to add it to the backend of your HAProxy config

```
backend application-backend
    balance     roundrobin
    log             global
    option http-server-close  
    option forwardfor
    reqadd Authorization:\ Basic\ am9obmRvZTphYmMxMjM=
```

Comment: I want to add one warning through, doing this will greatly increase the size of the headers, which will cause 400 Responses in web servers like Nginx

Comment: How should the configuration be if the authentication is for Nginx not HA? Or is it impossible to do it?